# Make an unsecure WiFi network available

Tags: android, linux, wifi, wireless, wifi-direct

I have a custom device that needs to offer peer-to-peer connection to mobile devices. The device runs Android and supports WiFi Direct, so connection to Android other devices can be made through WiFi Direct itself. Connection to a test laptop without WiFi Direct can be established by using the WiFi Direct backwards-compatible mode, in which an AP appears, and I can connect to it using WPS PBC. The problem is iOS devices.

AFAIK, iOS supports neither WiFi Direct or WPS. The only way to connect to the device would be by manually connecting to the AP and manually entering the passphrase. The problem is it that as part of the requirements I can't access the passphrase.

Is there a way to configure the autonomous WiFi P2P Group Owner be set up without a passphrase? Or is there a way to make an unsecure network available as a software AP using wpa_supplicant?

Thanks in advance for any ideas,

Janito

Answer (score 1):

To access the passphrase, see the following question that I answered: [WiFi Direct device connection with other Android devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25303112/wifi-direct-device-connection-with-other-android-devices/25714357#25714357)

If the Wi-Fi Direct group is a persistent group then the passphrase to access the group (as if it were a legacy AP) should be persistent.  However, when I was last working on Wi-Fi Direct last year, Samsung devices did not obey this policy.

There is no way to set the passphrase to one of your choosing, even though this feature has been requested in the past - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-platform/YrKKfEMACZk

To directly access wpa_supplicant, the device would at least need to be rooted.  I have not tried this, so I can not offer any further advice on this.